# C Opening a file to check if it is Binary, if so print it is binary

Tags: c, file-io, gnu

I've made a program that opens files and searches for a word

I want it to only work on TEXT Files

Is there a way provided by C to check if a file is BINARY, and if so, I want to exit the program before any operations take place

Thanks

Comment: Depends what your defn of binary is. Check every byte in the file isalphanum() or just if any are > 127 ?

Comment: All files are binary. MS has the distinction due to line endings

Comment: Checking the file ending won’t do the trick? Alternatively, you could check for the bytes for the ascii range of printable characters.

Comment: @Tob - Space, Tab are not printable

Comment: @EdHeal you’re right. Nevertheless, one could check for “allowed” bytes.

Comment: @EdHeal Space is printable.

Comment: Print leaves a mark on paper

Comment: @EdHeal I meant according to `isprint()`.

Comment: 'printf("is binary\n");'  done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't, because it's impossible to tell for sure. If you expect a specific encoding, you can check yourself whether the file contents are valid in this encoding, e.g. if you expect ASCII, all bytes must be <= `0x7f`. If you expect UTF-8, it's a bit more complicated, [see a description of it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8).

In any case, there's no guarantee that a "binary" file would not by accident look like a valid file in any given text encoding. In fact, the term "binary file" doesn't make too much sense, as all files contain binary data.

Comment: Right now this seems to work, I don't expect to be working on special symbols. I'm trying to produce a program that works like GREP on linux.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If we assume that by text you mean ASCII and not UTF-8, you can do this by reading each character and using `isascii()` and `isspace()` to check if it is a valid character:

```
void is_text(char *filename) {
    FILE *f = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!f) {
        perror("fopen failed");
        return;
    }
    int c;
    while ((c=fgetc(f) != EOF) {
        if ((!isascii(c) || iscntrl(c)) && !isspace(c)) {
            printf("is binary\n");
            fclose(f);
            return;
        }
    }
    printf("is text\n");
    fclose(f);
}
```

If the file contains UTF-8 characters, it becomes more complicated as you have to look at multiple bytes at once and see if they are valid UTF-8 byte sequences.  There's also the question of which Unicode code points are considered text.

Comment: I am trying to emulate the functioning of GREP in Linux, I don't think it works on unicode characters so I don't think it will be a problem. Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is typo in the answer: instead of `c=fgetc(c)` it must be `c=fgetc(f)`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the file per se which is binary or text; it is just about how you interpret the content of the file when opening it.
You may interpret a file containing solely text as binary, thereby avoiding that a `/r/n` might get translated to a `/n` only; And you may open a file containing raw data like, for example, a bitmap using a text mode, thereby probably corrupting the content in that a `0x0D 0x0A` gets converted to a `0x0D` only.

So you cannot check the file per se, but you may open the file in binary mode and see if the content contains anything which you do not interpret as text.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps: system(file "path/filename");